# change the src of an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="numbers">
  <iframe name="letters" src="">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the ability to click on any cell in the table, grab the value inside, show the `div` and append the `iframe src` based on the cell's value. When the user clicks on the cell again the `iframe` becomes blank and the `div` is hidden.

For example: click cell `one`, show the `div` with the `iframe src="/one.html"`. Click it again, hide the div with a blank `iframe`.

Thanks in advance!

(Please, no jQuery answers.)

Comment: `document.querySelector('iframe').src='http://y-u-no-search.internet';`

Answer (score 4):

Without adding an id to the `iframe` use this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src="http://example.com/";
```

Or based on the name:

```
document.getElementsByName("letters")[0].src="http://example.com/";
```

If you would add a id:

```
<iframe name="letters" id="letterframe" src="" />

document.getElementById("letterframe").src="http://example.com/";
```

Comment: Assuming the DOM only contains one `iframe` element.

Answer (score 0):

Added ids to some of the HTML elements.

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="numbers">
  <iframe id="iframe" name="letters" src="">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
document.getElementById('table').onclick=function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  e=e.target || e.srcElement;
  if(e.tagName.toLowerCase()=='td'){
    var page = e.innerHTML,iframe=document.getElementById('iframe');
    if(iframe.src.indexOf(page)>-1){
      document.getElementById('numbers').style.display='none';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('numbers').style.display='block';
      iframe.src='/'+page+'.html';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like below.Call this function on `onclick` event of `td` and pass desired `src` in parameter.

```
  <script type=”text/javascript”>
    function changeURL(srcvalue)
    {
    document.getElementById('letters').src=srcvalue;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: @rekire : go through standard attribute list in this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp link. Your all doubts will be cleared. BTW If have this info them why you used id attribute in ur answer ?

Comment: Sorry a little error of me. I mean the iframe has no id attribute **set**.